# Why if I put extra space or comment out a column from SELECT statement - all query run slower

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Weird thing happening.
Query below runs less than a second, but if I change anything(like extra space) in WHERE clause then the whole query running 7 seconds. 
Or if I comment out one of those lines `(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(...) ...`

Never see that before...

```
SELECT...
...
FROM ...
--If I put extra space after SELECT - the whole query running 7 seconds
    WHERE EXISTS
        (SELECT * FROM tblClaims_ReservePayments RP 
            WHERE 
            CASE WHEN @coverageTypeId IS NULL THEN 1 
            ELSE 
                CASE WHEN RP.CoverageTypeId = @coverageTypeId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END = 1 
        AND (DATEDIFF(d, @dateFrom, RP.DateCreated) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF(d, @dateTo, RP.DateCreated) <= 0) AND RP.ClaimId = C.ClaimId)
    AND
        CASE WHEN @companyGuid IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN CPI.CompanyGuid = @companyGuid THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END = 1
    AND 
        EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblClaims_Claimants CLMNT WHERE CLMNT.ClaimID = C.ClaimID AND CLMNT.StatusId = 0)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Adjusters WHERE adjuster = C.InhouseAdjuster)

    ORDER BY
        CPI.PolicyNumber
```

What is going on? 
Is it parameter sniffing?

The whole statement is below:

```
DECLARE
@dateFrom DATETIME = '2017-02-01',
@dateTo DATETIME = '2017-05-31',
@companyGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'A95645F7-74CF-4551-BD28-5CBC5AD77EF2',-- NULL, Philadelphia
@coverageTypeId INT = NULL,
@inhouseAdjuster varchar(8000) = NULL

DECLARE @Adjusters TABLE(adjuster uniqueidentifier)
IF(@inhouseAdjuster IS NOT NULL AND @inhouseAdjuster <> '')
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Adjusters
    SELECT Guid FROM dbo.StringOfGuidsToTable(@inhouseAdjuster, ',')
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Adjusters
    SELECT InhouseAdjuster FROM tblClaims_Claim
    END


DECLARE @AdjusterString varchar(500)
SET @AdjusterString = ''

DECLARE @CoveringTable TABLE (Covering varchar(1000))
INSERT INTO @CoveringTable
    SELECT DISTINCT tblUsers.FirstName + ' ' + tblUsers.LastName FROM tblClaims_Claim
    inner join tblUsers on tblUsers.userguid = tblClaims_Claim.userguid
    WHERE tblClaims_Claim.InhouseAdjuster IN (SELECT adjuster FROM @Adjusters)

SELECT @AdjusterString = @AdjusterString + CASE WHEN @AdjusterString = '' THEN '' ELSE ', ' END  + Covering FROM @CoveringTable



SELECT

    CPI.PolicyNumber,
    CC.DateReported,--------------------------------------added by Oleg 5/1/2017
    C.LossDate as ForfeitureDate,
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(ResPayAmount), 0) FROM tblClaims_ReservePayments RP INNER JOIN lstClaims_ReservePaymentTypes RPT ON RPT.ResPayTypeId = RP.ResPayTypeId AND RPT.ResPayTypedescription <> 'Expense' WHERE RP.ClaimId = C.ClaimId AND (DATEDIFF(d, @dateFrom, RP.DateCreated) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF(d, @dateTo, RP.DateCreated) <= 0) AND CASE WHEN @coverageTypeId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN RP.CoverageTypeId = @coverageTypeId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END = 1) AS [BondAmount],
    dbo.GetEntityName(CPI.InsuredGuid) as Defendant,
    CC.UserDef_ClaimantId as CaseNumber,
    CC.CorporationName, -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------added by Oleg 5/1/2017
    PRIM_ADDRESS.City,-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------added by Oleg 5/1/2017
    PRIM_ADDRESS.State,-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------added by Oleg 5/1/2017
    PRIM_ADDRESS.County,-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------added by Oleg 5/1/2017
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(ResPayAmount), 0) FROM tblClaims_ReservePayments RP INNER JOIN lstClaims_ReservePaymentTypes RPT ON RPT.ResPayTypeId = RP.ResPayTypeId AND RPT.ResPayTypedescription <> 'Expense' WHERE RP.ClaimId = C.ClaimId AND IsPayment = 1 AND (DATEDIFF(d, @dateFrom, RP.DateCreated) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF(d, @dateTo, RP.DateCreated) <= 0) AND CASE WHEN @coverageTypeId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN RP.CoverageTypeId = @coverageTypeId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END = 1) AS [ClaimsPaid],
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(ResPayAmount), 0) FROM tblClaims_ReservePayments RP INNER JOIN lstClaims_ReservePaymentTypes RPT ON RPT.ResPayTypeId = RP.ResPayTypeId AND RPT.ResPayTypedescription <> 'Expense' WHERE RP.ClaimId = C.ClaimId AND IsPayment = 0 AND (DATEDIFF(d, @dateFrom, RP.DateCreated) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF(d, @dateTo, RP.DateCreated) <= 0) AND CASE WHEN @coverageTypeId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN RP.CoverageTypeId = @coverageTypeId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END = 1) AS [ClaimsReserveRemaining],
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(ResPayAmount), 0) FROM tblClaims_ReservePayments RP INNER JOIN lstClaims_ReservePaymentTypes RPT ON RPT.ResPayTypeId = RP.ResPayTypeId AND RPT.ResPayTypedescription = 'Expense' WHERE RP.ClaimId = C.ClaimId AND (DATEDIFF(d, @dateFrom, RP.DateCreated) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF(d, @dateTo, RP.DateCreated) <= 0)AND CASE WHEN @coverageTypeId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN RP.CoverageTypeId = @coverageTypeId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END = 1) AS [AllocatedReserved],
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(ResPayAmount), 0) FROM tblClaims_ReservePayments RP INNER JOIN lstClaims_ReservePaymentTypes RPT ON RPT.ResPayTypeId = RP.ResPayTypeId AND RPT.ResPayTypedescription = 'Expense' WHERE RP.ClaimId = C.ClaimId AND IsPayment = 1 AND (DATEDIFF(d, @dateFrom, RP.DateCreated) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF(d, @dateTo, RP.DateCreated) <= 0) AND CASE WHEN @coverageTypeId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN RP.CoverageTypeId = @coverageTypeId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END = 1) AS [AllocatedPaid],
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(ResPayAmount), 0) FROM tblClaims_ReservePayments RP INNER JOIN lstClaims_ReservePaymentTypes RPT ON RPT.ResPayTypeId = RP.ResPayTypeId AND RPT.ResPayTypedescription = 'Expense' WHERE RP.ClaimId = C.ClaimId AND IsPayment = 0 AND (DATEDIFF(d, @dateFrom, RP.DateCreated) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF(d, @dateTo, RP.DateCreated) <= 0) AND CASE WHEN @coverageTypeId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN RP.CoverageTypeId = @coverageTypeId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END = 1) AS [AllocatedReserveRemaining],
    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Amount), 0) FROM tblClaims_ClaimExpenses CE WHERE CE.ClaimId = C.ClaimId AND (DATEDIFF(d, @dateFrom, CE.DateEntered) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF(d, @dateTo, CE.DateEntered) <= 0)) AS [UnAllocated]
FROM
    tblClaims_Claim C
INNER JOIN 
    tblClaims_PolicyInformation CPI
ON
    CPI.ClaimId = C.ClaimId
INNER JOIN tblClaims_Claimants CC ON C.ClaimId = CC.ClaimId  --AND CC.StatusId = 0  -----------------------------------added by Oleg 5/1/2017
INNER JOIN tblClaims_Addresses PRIM_ADDRESS ON PRIM_ADDRESS.AddressId = CC.AddressId ----------------------------------added by Oleg 5/1/2017
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 QuoteGUID FROM tblQuotes WHERE tblQuotes.ControlNo = C.ControlNo) t  ------------------------added by Oleg 5/1/2017
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM tblClaims_ReservePayments RP 
        WHERE 
        CASE WHEN @coverageTypeId IS NULL THEN 1 
        ELSE 
            CASE WHEN RP.CoverageTypeId = @coverageTypeId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END = 1 
    AND (DATEDIFF(d, @dateFrom, RP.DateCreated) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF(d, @dateTo, RP.DateCreated) <= 0) AND RP.ClaimId = C.ClaimId)
AND
    CASE WHEN @companyGuid IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN CPI.CompanyGuid = @companyGuid THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END = 1
AND 
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblClaims_Claimants CLMNT WHERE CLMNT.ClaimID = C.ClaimID AND CLMNT.StatusId = 0)
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Adjusters WHERE adjuster = C.InhouseAdjuster)

ORDER BY
    CPI.PolicyNumber
```

UPDATE:
If i put extra space in any line - it changes the performance to 7 sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a query is run, SQL Server compiles it into a query plan.

In order to match the same SQL query to this plan, the database generates a hash code for the query (called a "query hash") based on the query text.

If you change the query in any way-- even seemingly safe things like capitalization (where this does not affect the query), add spaces, add comments-- the query text is now different.  SQL Server will generate a different query hash for the query.

Given a new query hash, an existing query plan for this query hash will not be found.  Therefore the SQL optimizer will create a new query plan.  The new query plan is most likely very different than the old one-- possibly from parameter sniffing, as you suggested.

Commenting out functional parts of the query does actually change the query.  For example, commenting out a single line in a `SELECT` clause can drastically alter the performance of the query, because now SQL Server may not need that column from the table.  This means it could select a different index or skip a bookmark lookup, so performance can radically change.

Comment: Thanks. But I would assume if I ran it second time - it should use the new query execution plan and run fast. Is that right?

Comment: Not if subsequent runs use the same query plan that runs slowly.  I would expect a second run to be faster only if there was a lot of data loaded into memory from disk on the first run, so subsequent runs don't need to load the data.

Comment: Thanks Paul,  I did not know those details. OPTION (RECOMPILE) seems like doing the job. 
Good to know. Thanks